# How to make a union of two SetHashes in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

Given two `SetHash`es, one or both of them can be empty. I want to add all the elements of the second `SetHash` to the first one.

Since the output of the [union operator](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/(%7C)) is a `Set`, the only (and supposedly not the best one) way I managed to do it is the following.

```perl6
my SetHash $s1 = <a b c>.SetHash;
my SetHash $s2 = <c d e>.SetHash;
$s1 = ($s1 (|) $s2).SetHash; # SetHash(a b c d e)
```

**UPD:** Probably this is more simple, but having to convert to `.keys` makes me uncomfortable.

```perl6
$s1{ $s2.keys } X= True; # SetHash(a b c d e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm hoping Elizabeth Mattijsen will read over your question and our answers and either comment or provide her own answer. In the meantime here's my best shot:

```
my %s1 is SetHash = <a b c> ;
my %s2 is SetHash = <c d e> ;
%s1 = |%s1, |%s2 ; # SetHash(a b c d e)
```

Elizabeth implemented the `is Set` (and cousins ) capability for variables declared with the `%` sigil (i.e. variables that declare their primary nature to be [`Associative`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Associative)) in the Rakudo 2017.11 compiler release.

Prefix `|`, used within an expression that's an argument list, "flattens" its single argument if said single argument is composite (the [relevant doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_|) claims it must be a `Capture`, `Pair`, `List`, `Map`, or `Hash`):

```
say [ [1,2], [3,4]]; # [[1 2] [3 4]]
say [|[1,2], [3,4]]; # [1 2 [3 4]]
say [|1, 2, [3,4]];  # [1 2 [3 4]]
```

Comment: That's very elegant! So is it better to give the `%` sigil to `SetHash` variables?

Comment: Imo, usually, yes. Aiui, P6 sigils indicate whether **the compiler** should treat references to a given [symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) as a *singular* thing or a *plural* thing **at compile-time**. The compiler treats the `$` sigil as indicating a [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science%29)), i.e. a single thing. If you want the compiler to treat a symbol as referring to a *plural* [container](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers) that does the [`Associative`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Associative) role, you *must* use the `%` sigil.

Comment: Already the first line `my %s1 is SetHash = <a b c>` doesn't work on my machine, giving the following error: `Cannot modify an immutable SetHash (SetHash())`. I have version 2017.10.

Comment: `is SetHash` support was added with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/b6a4d5b55552045 , which puts it in the 2017.11 compiler release unfortunately.  So before that, your original answer `$s1 = ($s1 (|) $s2).SetHash` appears to be the best way to do it.  Mind you, coercing a `Set` to a `SetHash` is a relatively cheap operation, as they share the same internal structure.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Installed 2017.11, thanks! But my simple assignment doesn't work with the `%` sigil: `my SetHash %s1 = <a b c>.SetHash;` Does it mean that with `%` I should use only `is SetHash`?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky When you write `my SetHash %foo`, it means `%foo` stores objects of type `SetHash`. To make an associative-sigiled variable bind to a `SetHash` object, you should use the bind operator instead of `=`: `my %s1 := <a b c>.SetHash;`. Because when you write `my %foo =`, you're declaring a new variable and the right-hand side doesn't determine the type. I believe this is for non-scalars only, but I'm not sure I understand scalars enough to contain. They're containers that hold a reference.

Comment: @piojo Oh, that's my mistake. I usually write it in two lines: `my %s1; %s1 = <a b c>.SetHash;`

Comment: I would write that as `my %s1 is SetHash = <a b c>`.  This indicates that `%s1` is in fact a `SetHash`, so you can treat it as a `Hash`, but it will still have `SetHash` semantics.  Under the hood, this is similar to `my %s1 := <a b c>.SetHash`, but I think the syntax is more readable.